# bootpag - Not working Basic Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I am trying to use a plugin for dynamic pagination.

The plugin is-

**[Bootpag - Dynamic Pagination](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/)**

In the [Home page of the plugin](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/), I found an example, and I tried to use that as an example and what I have done is like this-

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">Dynamic Content goes here</div>
    <div id="page-selection">Pagination goes here</div>
    <script>
        // init bootpag
        $('#page-selection').bootpag({
            total: 10
        }).on("page", function(event, /* page number here */ num){
             $("#content").html(num); // Changing div content to dynamic content
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: if you are running this from you harddrive (*and not a server*) you will have to add the protocol to your urls. `http:` or `https:` at the start of the included files. As you see, the demo you posted in SO is working fine

Comment: I also tried in a server (this code, not local), but it is not working :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved it by this way-

```js
$('#show_paginator').bootpag({
      total: 23,
      page: 3,
      maxVisible: 10
}).on('page', function(event, num)
{
     $("#dynamic_content").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="dynamic_content">Pagination goes here</div>
<div id="show_paginator"></div>
```

---

More customised version-

```js
$('#show_paginator').bootpag({
       total: 53,
       page: 2,
       maxVisible: 5,
       leaps: true,
       firstLastUse: true,
       first: '←',
       last: '→',
       wrapClass: 'pagination',
       activeClass: 'active',
       disabledClass: 'disabled',
       nextClass: 'next',
       prevClass: 'prev',
       lastClass: 'last',
       firstClass: 'first'
}).on('page', function(event, num)
{
     $("#dynamic_content").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="dynamic_content">Pagination goes here</div>
<div id="show_paginator"></div>
```

---

Even more customization can be done by this **options**-

[image]

---

### Warning

Here I am using a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/jquery.bootpag.js) for showing content. But it is not recommended.

Hardly recommendation is to download **[this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js)** and put it locally.

Because there is no official CDN for bootpeg.

---

### Even More

If want to update paginator at run time, call the paginator like this-

```
$('#show_paginator').bootpag({total: 55});
```

---

Even more, can be found [**from here**](http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#.VyRB1_kdAV8).

---

I think u have your complete answer.

Comment: I dont get it, OP did just the similar things. What fixed it? Because I am not able to fix mine even with your code

Comment: there is no version for bootstrap 4 using this bootpage??

Comment: @Gladiador I know this is an old comment, but for the future, I made a pull request on the git repo to support Bootstrap 4